# RestTemplate XML deserialize null on empty tag with attributes

Tags: java, spring, deserialization, resttemplate, objectmapper

I have the following response, when values are in attributes and `my` tag has no values except attributes (also level and my can have multiple values)

```
<main>
<level id="1">
<my id="111" amount="100000.00"/>
</level>
<level id="2">
<my id="121" amount="5000.00"/>
</level>
<level id="3">
<my id="122" amount="500.00"/>
</level>
</main>
```

When trying to deserialize `my` is null

```
  ResponseEntity<RequestVO> jackpotFeederResponse = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.build(), HttpMethod.GET,
                    HttpEntity.EMPTY, RequestVO.class);
```

I try adding different `DeserializationFeature`, but failed

```
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_IGNORED_PROPERTIES, true);
            objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_ARRAY_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
            converter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(converter);
```

My POJOs:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "main", namespace = "")
@Data
public class RequestVO implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1382015668147149795L;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "level")
    ArrayList<LevelVO> levelList;
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "level", namespace = "")
@Data
public class LevelVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1382015668147149795L;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    String id;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "my")
    ArrayList<MyVO> myList;


@XmlRootElement(name = "my", namespace = "")
@Data
public class MyVO implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1382015668147149795L;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    String id;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `JacksonXmlRootElement`? ..and https://stackoverflow.com/q/48157538/592355 might help (`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false` !?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should use the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)` on your collection types. Next up try not to mix JAXB Annotations with Jackson ones. Therefor just use @JacksonXmlRootElement instead of @XmlRootElement.

Your XML POJOs should look like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "main")
@Data
public class RequestVO implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "level")
    ArrayList<LevelVO> levelList;
}


@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "level")
@Data
public class LevelVO implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    String id;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "my")
    ArrayList<MyVO> myList;
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "my")
@Data
public class MyVO implements Serializable {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "id", isAttribute = true)
    String id;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "amount", isAttribute = true)
    String amount;
}
```

If you really want to stick to use the @XmlRootElement Annotation. It could be that you also have to register the JaxbAnnotationModule to Jacksons XmlMapper:

```
JaxbAnnotationModule module = new JaxbAnnotationModule();
xmlMapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: It's working, Why not using `XmlRootElement`? actually java docs states *It is similar to JAXB <code>XmlRootElement</code>*

Comment: You can use `@XmlRootElement`, as I said in my last paragraph. But depending on the Jackson version you are using, you may need to register the JaxbAnnotationModule for Jackson so that Jackson does not ignore the `@XmlRootElement` annotations. And since you have already used the `@JacksonXmlProperty` annotation, why would you mix JAXB and Jackson annotations?